# returns a unique words dictionary whose keys are numbers and whose values are lists of equal length words

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wrote a function n_letter_dictionary(my_string) to get a dictionary whose keys are numbers and whose values are lists that contain unique words. Here the number of letters of a word is equal to the key. Here is my code:

```
def n_letter_dictionary(my_string):
    my_string = my_string.lower().split()

    L= []
    for key in my_string:
        if len(key) >1:
            l={len(key):[key]}
            L.append(l)
    L.sort()         
    return L
s="The way you see people is the way you treat them and the Way you treat them is what they become"
print(n_letter_dictionary(s))
```

Correct output should be:

```
{2: ['is'], 3: ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5: ['treat'], 6: ['become', 'people']}
```

Whereas my code gives following output:

```
[{2: ['is']}, {2: ['is']}, {3: ['and']}, {3:['see']},{3:['the']},{3:['the']},{3:['the']}, {3:['way']}, {3:['way']},{3:['way']},{3:['you']}, {3:['you']},{3:['you']}, {4:['them']}, {4:['them']}, {4:['they']},{4:['what']},{5: ['treat']},{5: ['treat']},{ 6:['become']}, {6:['people']}]
```

How could I get correct output?

Comment: Make _dict of sets_, not _list of deicts_. Also collections.defaultdict can be useful

Comment: Is the order of the words in the lists of the correct output important?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) which can be used to automatically make sets for each entry as follows. This would ensure only unique entries are stored:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def n_letter_dictionary(my_string):
    words = my_string.lower().split()
    lengths = defaultdict(set)

    for key in words:
        if len(key) > 1:
            lengths[len(key)].add(key)

    return {key : sorted(value) for key, value in lengths.items()}

s = "The way you see people is the way you treat them and the Way you treat them is what they become"
lengths = n_letter_dictionary(s)

for key in sorted(lengths.keys()):
    print(key, lengths[key])
```

Note, you cannot sort a dictionary, but you can display the contents in a sorted out:

```
2 ['is']
3 ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you']
4 ['them', 'they', 'what']
5 ['treat']
6 ['become', 'people']
```

Comment: This is not producing the desired result.

Comment: Just spotted that, have fixed

Comment: I also suppose OP does not want words of length 1 by looking at his code.

Comment: @Evans, list of values need to be sorted alphabetically. You see I and @ timegeb already posted corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a oneliner, notice you may have empty list with this method:

```
In[12]: {k:list(set(filter(lambda x: len(x) == v, s.split()))) for k,v in enumerate(range(max(map(len, s.split()))))}
Out[12]: 
{0: [],
 1: [],
 2: ['is'],
 3: ['and', 'Way', 'you', 'see', 'way', 'the', 'The'],
 4: ['them', 'what', 'they'],
 5: ['treat']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a new dictionary for every key you encounter and append it to a list.

My suggestion is to use a `defaultdict` with the empty set as the default value in order to avoid appending duplicates (this could be done with a list as well, but with an O(n) membership test as opposed to O(1) for the set). The sorting and conversion to lists can be done after you have accumulated all the words for all word lengths.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> 
>>> for word in s.lower().split():
...     the_len = len(word)
...     if the_len > 1:
...         d[the_len].add(word)
... 
>>> d = {k:sorted(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> d
{2: ['is'], 3: ['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], 4: ['them', 'they', 'what'], 5: ['treat'], 6: ['become', 'people']}
```

If you don't want to use a `defaultdict`, you can use a regular `dict` and change the line

```
d[the_len].add(word)
```

to

```
d.setdefault(the_len, set()).add(word)
```

Comment: your list of values are not in ascending order

Comment: alphabetical order for list of values

Comment: @ohid it's pretty simple to sort the list if that's what you need. `sorted(v)` instead of `list(v)`

Answer (score 0):

I made the following code which gives correct output:

```
def n_letter_dictionary(my_string):
    from collections import defaultdict
    my_string = my_string.lower().split()

    L= []
    for key in my_string:
        if len(key) >=1:
            l=(len(key),key)
            L.append(l)

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in L:
        d[k].append(v)
    values=d.items()
    return_dic={}
    for k, v in values:
        return_dic[k]=sorted(list(set(v)))
    return return_dic
```

Thanks